# ionic and $cordovaPush

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push

i'm new here :D

I has the next code:

```
alert('hi');
$cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
  alert('push' + result);
}, function (err) {
   alert('error);
});
alert('bye');
```

And when I go to Ionic View I get the alerts: "hi" and "bye", BUT never the "push" or "error"...

I install:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
```

and I put the ng-cordova.js and PushNotification.js in the index...

What happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

View the [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) plugins it's easy for you.
for example :

```
 var androidConfig = {
        "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    };
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
   });
```

above code added in app.js file. its try  Best Of Luck.

Comment: I view http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/ and I copy paste and I get the same results...

Comment: Nothing, I tried and tried and nothing. I get Ripple and it said "PushNotification is not defined"... Maybe deviceready is doesn't working :s

Comment: Yup, is working. I get "PushNotification is not defined" after I get "PushNotification...init". So, i have a problem with deviceready I guess

Comment: It's work for me , your sender is correct ?  ,and which device are used for testing.

Comment: I'm trying with iosConfig (same at page Cordova), and i tested with Ionic View, Browser, Ripple, iOS Emulate and Run... and nothing

Comment: Most of the Cordova plugins not working in ionic view browser but anyway I am tested on only Android.

Comment: Because last time I am trying to test in ionic view it's not working then I am installed in device .it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not right

check the error like this

```
alert('hi');
$cordovaPush.register(config)

.then(function (result) {
  alert('push' + result);
})

.fail(function (err){
  alert(err);
})

alert('bye');
```